# Call function destroyed callback in last call

Tags: javascript

I have function, which create popup similar as alert, confirm or prompt. Problem occurs when is called new popup (any type), then is destroyed callback in first call (prompt value)

```
PoppyPopup.prompt('Type your name', 'User control', {}, function(value) {
    PoppyPopup.alert('Welcome ' + value); //<-- value is id of second popup
});

PoppyPopup.alert('Hi, this is a PopUp!', 'With title!');
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/yojz8sb3/

**Edit**: When is call one time, it's OK, I really dont know where is problem.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer. I've updated it further since you accepted it to include a rewrite of PoppyPopup that should be more stable and easier to read/understand. Hope it helps.

Comment: @RockySims Cool! I dont think that someone help with re-design, so thank you so much.. meanwhile, when I was waiting on response, I was thinking about more shorter code, like https://jsfiddle.net/6et5v4wd/1/ - join alert, confirm and prompt join to one toghether (becase code is almoust same - different is just cancelCallback which can be undefined and no error occure), but `constructor.name` doesnt work

Comment: @RockySims but shorter code with your solution is away - it's OK :) - It need just callback on input to validate value or/and avoid accept if callback is not `return true;` and all right! If you want help me or not, anyway thanks for your solution with Promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the short answer is because PoppyPopup isn't designed to handle having more than one popup open at a time.

`popupType` is shared between all popups so when you open the `alert` popup it sets `popupType` to `ALERT` and so when the prompt popup's `accept` callback is called it's handled as if it's an `ALERT` type popup.

---

One (fairly hacky) solution is to remove `var popupType = null;` and instead pass `popupType` to the `Popup` constructor as a 4th argument. Then you can change

```
PoppyPopup.accept(basePopup.id, options);
```

to

```
PoppyPopup.accept(basePopup.id, options, popupType);
```

in `Popup` function.

And change

```
accept: function(popupId, options) {
```

to

```
accept: function(popupId, options, popupType) {
```

that way the popup type is associated with the popup instance instead of being shared among all popups.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0xpz7f9L/

---

However my answer above doesn't fix the issue that clicking the accept button appears to close a random popup (obviously not ideal). I'd recommend rewriting the whole thing to simplify it and make it easier to read/understand. Also this sort of thing traditionally uses promises instead of callbacks.

Here is how I would rewrite it:

```js
const PoppyPopup = (function() {
  let nextPopupId = 0;

  return {
    alert: function(message, title, options) {
      const realOptions = buildOptionsFrom(options);
      const popupElem = buildPopupElem(title, message, realOptions, false, false);

      const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        popupElem.querySelector('.accept').onclick = resolve;
      });
      promise.finally(() => close(popupElem, realOptions.removeWhenClosed));
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(popupElem);

      return promise;
    },

    confirm: function(message, title, options) {
      const realOptions = buildOptionsFrom(options);
      const popupElem = buildPopupElem(title, message, realOptions, false, true);

      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        popupElem.querySelector('.accept').onclick = resolve;
        popupElem.querySelector('.cancel').onclick = reject;
      });
      promise.finally(() => close(popupElem, realOptions.removeWhenClosed));
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(popupElem);

      return promise;
    },

    prompt: function(message, title, options) {
      const realOptions = buildOptionsFrom(options);
      const popupElem = buildPopupElem(title, message, realOptions, true, true);

      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        popupElem.querySelector('.accept').onclick = () => resolve(popupElem.querySelector('input').value);
        popupElem.querySelector('.cancel').onclick = reject;
      });
      promise.finally(() => close(popupElem, realOptions.removeWhenClosed));
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(popupElem);

      return promise;
    }
  };
  
  function close(popupElem, removeWhenClosed) {
    popupElem.classList.remove('show');

    popupElem.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
      if (e.propertyName === 'opacity' && removeWhenClosed) {
        popupElem.parentNode.removeChild(popupElem);
      }
    });
  }
  
  function buildOptionsFrom(options) {
    return Object.assign({
      showBackground: true,
      removeWhenClosed: true,
      width: '400px'
    }, options || {});
  }

  function buildPopupElem(title, message, options, provideInput, provideCancel) {
    const basePopupDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    basePopupDiv.className = "poppy-popup show";
    basePopupDiv.id = nextPopupId++;
    
    if (options.showBackground) { 
      const backgroundDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
      backgroundDiv.className = "poppy-popup-background";
      basePopupDiv.appendChild(backgroundDiv);
    }
    
    const containerDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    containerDiv.className = "poppy-popup-container";
    containerDiv.style.width = options.width;
    containerDiv.style.height = options.height;
    
    if (title) {
      const headerTitleDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
      headerTitleDiv.className = "poppy-popup-title-text";
      headerTitleDiv.innerHTML = title;
    
      const headerDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
      headerDiv.className = "poppy-popup-header";
      headerDiv.appendChild(headerTitleDiv);

      containerDiv.appendChild(headerDiv);
    }
    
    const contentDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    contentDiv.className = "poppy-popup-content";
    contentDiv.innerHTML = message;
    
    if (provideInput) {
      const input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.type = "text";
      contentDiv.appendChild(input);
    }
    
    const acceptLink = document.createElement("A");
    acceptLink.className = 'accept';
    acceptLink.href = "#";
    acceptLink.innerHTML = "<i class='material-icons'>done</i> OK";
    
    const acceptSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
    acceptSpan.className = "poppy-popup-accept";
    acceptSpan.appendChild(acceptLink);
    
    const buttonsDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    buttonsDiv.className = "poppy-popup-buttons";
    buttonsDiv.appendChild(acceptSpan);
    
    if (provideCancel) {
      const cancelLink = document.createElement("A");
      cancelLink.className = "cancel";
      cancelLink.href = "#";
      cancelLink.innerHTML = "<i class='material-icons'>close</i> Cancel";
    
      const cancelSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
      cancelSpan.className = "poppy-popup-cancel";
      cancelSpan.appendChild(cancelLink);
      
      buttonsDiv.appendChild(cancelSpan);
    }
    
    containerDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
    containerDiv.appendChild(buttonsDiv);

    basePopupDiv.appendChild(containerDiv);

    return basePopupDiv;
  } //end of buildPopupElem()
})();

PoppyPopup.prompt('Type your name', 'User control').then(value => {
  PoppyPopup.alert('Welcome ' + value).then(() => {
    PoppyPopup.confirm('And just for completeness, confirm?')
      .then(() => alert('accepted'), () => alert('rejected'));
  });
});

PoppyPopup.alert('Hi, this is a PopUp!', 'With title!');
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #eeeeee; }

.poppy-popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s; }
  .poppy-popup.show {
    opacity: 1; }
  .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1010;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
  .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1020;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
    .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-header {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      color: #222222;
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px; }
      .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-header > .poppy-popup-title-text {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 50px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        font-weight: bold;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap; }
    .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-content {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
      border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
      overflow: auto; }
      .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-content > input[type="text"] {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-width: 0;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
        box-shadow: none;
        transition: border-bottom .2s; }
        .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-content > input[type="text"]:focus {
          border-bottom: 2px solid #2088AD; }
    .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      padding: 0 10px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      overflow: hidden; }
      .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-accept, .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-cancel {
        width: 120px;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        color: #2088AD; }
        .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-accept > a, .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-cancel > a {
          display: block;
          color: inherit;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px 0;
          border-radius: 3px;
          transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .1s; }
          .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-accept > a:active, .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-cancel > a:active {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
          .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-accept > a > i, .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-cancel > a > i {
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-top: -3px; }
      .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-accept {
        right: 0;
        color: #2088AD; }
        .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-accept > a:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
      .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-cancel {
        left: 0;
        color: #2088AD; }
        .poppy-popup > .poppy-popup-container > .poppy-popup-buttons > .poppy-popup-cancel > a:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
```

Note: The css is unchanged.